# Templates folder missing in Microsoft Visual Studio for C#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

[how visual studio looks like for me at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Ux5.png)

This question was previously asked and I did click the "Open Visual Studio Installer" link. When installing, I also check marked the ".NET Desktop develepment move and clicked "Modify" but still no luck. Does anyone have a solution to this or have run into the same problem?

The version I'm using is Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Community version on a Windows 7 Enterprise OS.

Comment: You can click on modify installation under file menu. This will open the VS installer and you can double check whether you've selected .Net option or not

Comment: I don't see a "modify Installation" in the file menu

Answer (score 1):

If you look in \Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates or \Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates, do you see any templates installed there?

Try re-registering your templates by issuing this command from the VS Command prompt:

```
devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates
```